# How to reduce the fill in many nodes for tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz image which I plan to show, and then show a new version with a node highlighted and the others muted.  I'd like to change the fill amount for all the nodes within SSS and SSI to be, say `fill=color!50`.  (for what it's worth this is sitting within a much larger figure which I'll be wanting to do this to).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{colorS}{RGB}{0,154,128}
\definecolor{colorI}{RGB}{255,32,0}
\tikzstyle{SusCirc}=[circle,draw=black!50,fill=colorS!90,thick, minimum size=2mm]%a circle
                                %representing a susceptible individual
\tikzstyle{InfCirc}=[circle,draw=black!50,fill=colorI!90,thick, minimum size=2mm]%a circle
                                %representing an infected individual
\tikzstyle{BigCirc}=[circle,draw=black!50,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt]


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[BigCirc] (SSS) at (0.000000, 0.000000) {\scalebox{0.25}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (center) at (0.000000,0.000000) {};
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (left) at (1.000000,0.000000) {};
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (top) at (-1.000000,0.000000) {};
  \draw [-] (center) -- (left);
  \draw [-] (center) -- (top);
\end{tikzpicture}}};


\node[BigCirc] (SSI) at (2.954020, -1.762016) {\scalebox{0.25}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (center) at (0.000000,0.000000) {};
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (left) at (1.000000,0.000000) {};
  \node[InfCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (top) at (-1.000000,0.000000) {};
  \draw [-] (center) -- (left);
  \draw [-] (center) -- (top);
\end{tikzpicture}}};


\node[BigCirc] (SIS) at (4.237137, -0.360863) {\scalebox{0.25}{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (center) at (0.000000,0.000000) {};
  \node[InfCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (left) at (1.000000,0.000000) {};
  \node[SusCirc, minimum size = 8mm] (top) at (-1.000000,0.000000) {};
  \draw [-] (center) -- (left);
  \draw [-] (center) -- (top);
\end{tikzpicture}}};

  \draw [-] (SSS) -- (SSI);
  \draw [-] (SSS) -- (SIS);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the current appearance. [image] (apologies - apparently firewall blocked my first upload???)

As noted: I'd like to change the fill amount for all the nodes within SSS and SSI to be, say `fill=color!50`. There must be a way to do that without having to edit each node.

To be explicit: I would like to write a single command that changes the fill fraction of all nodes within one of my `BigCirc`s.  What I gave was a minimal working example, but what I have has a lot more nodes in it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How are you showing this? Is it part of a Beamer presentation by any chance? But nesting TikZ pictures is trouble, as others have said. Weird stuff happens which means the obvious Beamer solutions might not work without changing the structure.

Comment: I'm writing a textbook

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally I think nesting `tikzpicture`s is something to avoid. For this you may try to define a `pic`, which was introduced with TikZ 3.0. In this case that lets you easily modify the `fill opacity` (or just `opacity`, which affects the outer circle as well), as seen in the example below.

Here I define a `pic` that takes three arguments, which are styles for the three small circles, first argument is for the left circle, second for middle, third for right.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\definecolor{colorS}{RGB}{0,154,128}
\definecolor{colorI}{RGB}{255,32,0}
\tikzset{
%a circle representing a susceptible individual
SusCirc/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=colorS!90, minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt},
%a circle representing an infected individual
InfCirc/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=colorI!90,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt},
BigCirc/.style={circle,draw=black!50,thick,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=0pt},
%
pics/circles/.style args={#1#2#3}{
code={
 \node [#1] (LeftDot) at (0,0) {};
 \node [#2,right=2pt of LeftDot] (CenterDot) {};
 \node [#3,right=2pt of CenterDot] (RightDot) {};
 \draw (LeftDot) -- (CenterDot) -- (RightDot);
 \node[BigCirc, fit = (LeftDot)(RightDot)] (circ)  {};
}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (SSS) at (0.000000, 0.000000) {circles={SusCirc}{SusCirc}{SusCirc}};
\pic (SSI) at (2.954020, -1.762016) {circles={InfCirc}{SusCirc}{SusCirc}};
\pic (SIS) at (4.237137, -0.360863) {circles={SusCirc}{SusCirc}{InfCirc}};

\draw (SSScirc) -- (SSIcirc);
\draw (SSScirc) -- (SIScirc);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (SSS) at (0.000000, 0.000000) {circles={SusCirc}{SusCirc}{SusCirc}};
\pic (SSI) [fill opacity=0.2] at (2.954020, -1.762016) {circles={InfCirc}{SusCirc}{SusCirc}};
\pic (SIS) [opacity=0.2] at (4.237137, -0.360863) {circles={SusCirc}{SusCirc}{InfCirc}};

\draw (SSScirc) -- (SSIcirc);
\draw (SSScirc) -- (SIScirc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Old code - three different `pic`s

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{colorS}{RGB}{0,154,128}
\definecolor{colorI}{RGB}{255,32,0}
\tikzset{
%a circle representing a susceptible individual
SusCirc/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=colorS!90, minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt},
%a circle representing an infected individual
InfCirc/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=colorI!90,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt},
BigCirc/.style={circle,draw=black!50,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt},
%
allgrey/.pic={
\node [draw=black!50,thick,circle,minimum size=8mm,inner sep=0pt] (OuterCircle) {};
\node [SusCirc,right=0.4pt] (LeftDot) at (OuterCircle.west) {};
\node [SusCirc,left=0.4pt] (RightDot) at (OuterCircle.east) {};
\node [SusCirc] (CenterDot) at (OuterCircle.center) {};
\draw (LeftDot) -- (CenterDot) -- (RightDot);
},
%
leftred/.pic={
\node [draw=black!50,thick,circle,minimum size=8mm,inner sep=0pt] (OuterCircle) {};
\node [InfCirc,right=0.4pt] (LeftDot) at (OuterCircle.west) {};
\node [SusCirc,left=0.4pt] (RightDot) at (OuterCircle.east) {};
\node [SusCirc] (CenterDot) at (OuterCircle.center) {};
\draw (LeftDot) -- (CenterDot) -- (RightDot);
},
rightred/.pic={
\node [draw=black!50,thick,circle,minimum size=8mm,inner sep=0pt] (OuterCircle) {};
\node [SusCirc,right=0.4pt] (LeftDot) at (OuterCircle.west) {};
\node [InfCirc,left=0.4pt] (RightDot) at (OuterCircle.east) {};
\node [SusCirc] (CenterDot) at (OuterCircle.center) {};
\draw (LeftDot) -- (CenterDot) -- (RightDot);
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (SSS) at (0.000000, 0.000000) {allgrey};
\pic (SSI) at (2.954020, -1.762016) {leftred};
\pic (SIS) at (4.237137, -0.360863) {rightred};

\draw (SSSOuterCircle) -- (SSIOuterCircle);
\draw (SSSOuterCircle) -- (SISOuterCircle);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (SSS) [fill opacity=0.5] at (0.000000, 0.000000) {allgrey};
\pic (SSI) [fill opacity=0.5] at (2.954020, -1.762016) {leftred};
\pic (SIS) at (4.237137, -0.360863) {rightred};

\draw (SSSOuterCircle) -- (SSIOuterCircle);
\draw (SSSOuterCircle) -- (SISOuterCircle);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This still leaves me having to explicitly state the fill fraction for each node.  I've got a big figure with many nodes like this.  I'd like a more global command to do this.

Comment: @Joel It's one statement for each big circle/"group", rather than one statement for each of the three smaller circles within a group, which is what I thought you were after. To be honest, I can't at the moment see how to make this much simpler.

Comment: @Joel Perhaps you could say roughly what kind of syntax you would like to have, and what it should produce from which input.

Comment: In terms of my own notation, I'd like a command associated with each `BigCirc` that causes the fill fraction of all nodes within it to go down.  In my actual figure, there are more than 3 nodes in each `BigCirc` and 16 different `BigCirc`s.  So I want a single command that will gray out a group of nodes.

Comment: @Joel Edit that info into the question as well, so that other answerers will more easily see it.

Comment: I've added it, but I didn't want to restrict exactly what form the solution takes.  That's why I initially said that I had many nodes and wanted a way to do it without editing each node.

Comment: @Joel At the moment I don't have any other suggestions, so I'm going to leave my answer as is. And I'm probably being a bit stupid, but I don't really see how this doesn't answer your question as stated. I mean, `\pic {leftred};` prints the `BigCirc` with the left dot red, `\pic [fill opacity=0.5] {leftred};` prints exactly the same, but with a reduced fill opacity. Your edited text says *I would like to write a single command that changes the fill fraction of all nodes within one of my BigCircs*, which is more or less exactly what `[fill opacity=0.5]` does in the above example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30690/discussion-between-joel-and-torbjorn-t).

Answer (score 3):

Try use node options for determining opacity for highlight of nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning}
    \definecolor{colorS}{RGB}{0,154,128}
    \definecolor{colorI}{RGB}{255,32,0}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1mm,
      start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {draw=black!50, circle,
                     inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
                     node contents={}},
   SusCirc/.style = {fill=colorS!#1,% #1 determine color intensity 
                     join=by -, on chain},
   InfCirc/.style = {fill=colorI!#1, join=by -, on chain},
   BigCirc/.style = {very thick}
                        ]
\node (s11) [SusCirc=90];
\node (s12) [SusCirc=90];
\node (s13) [SusCirc=90];
    \node (SSS) [BigCirc,fit=(s11) (s13)];
%
\node (s21) [SusCirc=90,reset,
             below right=0mm and 55mm of SSS];
\node (s22) [SusCirc=90];
\node (s23) [InfCirc=90];
    \node (SSI) [BigCirc,fit=(s21) (s23)];
%
\node (s31) [InfCirc=50,reset,
             below right=21mm and 33mm of SSS];
\node (s32) [SusCirc=60];
\node (s33) [SusCirc=30];
    \node (ISS) [BigCirc,fit=(s31) (s33)];
%
\draw (SSS) -- (SSI) (SSS) -- (ISS); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For simpler and compact code I use three tikz libraries: `chain` (for positioning of small circles), `fit` (for fitting big circles around smalls and with this avoiding nesting of tikz pictures) and `positioning` (for positioning of circles groups). Use of option for color intensity should be self describing.

[image]

**Edit:** Further simplification of my code can be obtained by use of function `default`. With it above code is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,positioning}
    \definecolor{colorS}{RGB}{0,154,128}
    \definecolor{colorI}{RGB}{255,32,0}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{reset/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1mm,
      start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {draw=black!50, circle,
                     inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm,
                     node contents={}},
   SusCirc/.style = {fill=colorS!#1,% #1 determine color intensity 
                     join=by -, on chain},
SusCirc/.default = 90,
   InfCirc/.style = {fill=colorI!#1, join=by -, on chain},
InfCirc/.default = 90,
   BigCirc/.style = {very thick},
                        ]
\node (s11) [SusCirc];
\node (s12) [SusCirc];
\node (s13) [SusCirc];
    \node (SSS) [BigCirc,fit=(s11) (s13)];
%
\node (s21) [SusCirc,reset,
             below right=0mm and 55mm of SSS];
\node (s22) [SusCirc];
\node (s23) [InfCirc];
    \node (SSI) [BigCirc,fit=(s21) (s23)];
%
\node (s31) [InfCirc=50,reset,
             below right=21mm and 33mm of SSS];
\node (s32) [SusCirc=60];
\node (s33) [SusCirc=30];
    \node (ISS) [BigCirc,fit=(s31) (s33)];
%
\draw (SSS) -- (SSI) (SSS) -- (ISS); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Well, this is still not what you like to obtain, however, try the following:

```
\begin{scope}[fill opacity=0.5% or whatever value you like to have
             ]
\node (s31) [InfCirc,reset,
             below right=21mm and 33mm of SSS];
\node (s32) [SusCirc];
\node (s33) [SusCirc];
\end{scope}
```

If this is satisfactory, than you can omit options for fill of SusCirc and InCirc as well default settings.